# Cannot loop through custom array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel-4

Using Laravel 4 and trying to create an array of objects without using eloquent.

That array is made this like:

```
$item_collection[] = [
    'item_type' => $item->item_type->name,

];
```

This returns a long list of items in an array:

```
array(258) {
  [0] array(1) {
    ["item_type"] "Deal Bag"
  }
  [1] array(1) {
    ["item_type"] "Car"
  }
  [2] array(1) {
    ["item_type"] "Deal Bag"
  }
}
```

In my view I am trying to loop like normal:

```
@foreach ($items as $item)
  <tr>
    <td>{{ $item->item_type }}</td>
  </tr>
@endforeach
```

But receiving "Trying to get property of non-object" for all the values.

Where am I going wrong either with making / looping this array?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$item['item_type']` since you have an array, not an object?

Comment: duh. Of course it is! Thanks for reminding me on that one.

Answer (score 0):

Try using array notation:

```
{{ $item['item_type'] }}
```